# Spring Java based configuration with static method

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-java-config

can any one please advice why we need to declare PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean using a **static** method ? I just found that if I use non-static for below then url will be set to null value instead of taking from property file -

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String url;

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfig(String profile) {
    String propertyFileName = "application_"+profile+".properties";
    System.out.println(propertyFileName);
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(propertyFileName));
    return configurer;
}   

@Bean
@Profile("local")
public static String localProfile(){
    return "local";
}

@Bean
@Profile("prod")
public static String prodProfile(){
    return "prod";
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` objects are responsible for resolving `@Value` annotations against the current Spring Environment and its set of PropertySources. `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` class implements `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. In the container lifecycle, a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` object must be instantiated earlier than an object of `@Configuration`-annotated class.

If you have `@Configuration`-annotated class with instance method returning a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` object, then the container can not instantiate the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` object without instantiating the `@Configuration`-annotated class object itself. In this case, `@Value` can not be resolved, since the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` object does not exist at the moment of instantiation of the object of `@Configuration`-annotated class. Thus, `@Value`-annotated field takes the default value, which is `null`.

Please see the "Bootstrapping" part of `@Bean` [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) for more information.